# Max Function Isn't Working in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I just want to find the max value from the `Visitor` table. Last is working fine but when digit come VI9999 after that it always returns max value same not VI10000. Please Suggest me what I will do for this...

Thanks in Advance..

Sql query:

```
select MAX(TSID) 
FROM VISITOR_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Max(cast(substring(TSID, 3, 10) as int)) 
FROM VISITOR_TABLE;
```